Tightening a kitchen faucet without a visible nut
I've been trying to tighten my kitchen faucet which is very loose. Unfortunately, none of the videos online seem to look like my set-up (see attached).
There seems to be some sort of black plastic cover or bracket and I'm not sure as to whether I need to take it off or use it to tighten the nut.

the nubs on the black tube are not for decoration ... they are finger holds

Yeah, I'm guessing that the black plastic thing is the nut, and it's meant to be tightened by hand.

Yep worked like a charm, thanks! Feel free to write it up as an answer to get the credit.
